# Is there a standard keyboard shortcut to build the current project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> launches a solution build, but I would like a shortcut that just builds the current project. Is a custom shortcut my only option?

**Edit:** Looks like a custom shortcut is my only option as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> does not work for me.

Comment: alt+b+u    (build unit)

Comment: Verified this on Visual Studio 2012!

Comment: Ctrl+F6 does it in up to VS2013 but no longer in VS2015 (RC at least).

Comment: Alt+b+u is a way to hit the menu option; the command Build.BuildSelection. You may be already assigned to Shift + F6 or you can assign it in the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @Omu's answer should be accepted answer

Comment: Alt+b+u (build unit) - Tested on VS2015 as well.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Assigning the shortcut to "Build.BuildOnlyProject" command doesn't seem to work in VS2008.

Assign the shortcut to **"Build.BuildSelection"**.  If you have a solution with several projects and files open from the various projects, whatever file you are currently editing will define the project that will be built when you use the assigned shortcut for "Build.BuildSelection".

You'll know the keyboard shortcut is working when you click the Build menu option and you see the keyboard shortcut on the menu itself.

btw -  a restart/reboot is not required when assigning keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if you don't select the project in the Solution Explorer

Comment: You need a file open and have focus on the file; the project the file belongs to will build with Build.BuildSelection.

Comment: @Keith Nicholas has the answer below. I verified it works in VS2010: ALT-B (hold ALT) U

Comment: @D-Money, Alt+B is the keyboard shortcut to open the Visual Studio Build Menu and the U is the keyboard shortcut to build from within the Build menu. You need to define a custom keyboard shortcut as described in this answer.

Comment: To assign keyboard shortcuts, it is in menu TOOLS\Options\Environment\Keyboard

Comment: I assigned `ctrl`+`B` to build the project. This is a logical shortcut for standard `ctrl`+`shift`+`B` to build the solution.

Comment: anyone know why build only project is broken? should it be reported or is it intended for use from a different context?

Comment: @PrashanthSubramanian - post a new question with reproducible steps. If you're unfamiliar with how StackOverflow works, read through the help: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 84):

custom shortcut depending on what keybindings you are using.....if you look in your menu it will tell you if you have a keybinding.

The other thing I have got used to, because I make use of ViEmu, is use the menu shortcuts. Which are actually quite quick to do, and are independent of bindings.

- So to build your project you go <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: Oooh that damn keyboard shortcut window is insidious..hundreds of actions in a listbox with only 4 viewable lines and no resize

Comment: I know!  I keep wondering when they will redesign it, its been like that for a few versions now!

Comment: I guess the search function works pretty well for paring it down as long as you know what you're looking for.

Comment: There's a whole world waiting for you with menu shortcuts.  While they read like cheat controls for old games, they're good to master.

Answer (score 82):

You can use the shortcuts already established in the main menu that are navigated with the Alt key:

At least for VS2013:

```
Alt + B, B -> Build Solution
Alt + B, R -> Rebuild Solution
Alt + B, U -> Build current project
Alt + B, E -> Rebuild current project
```

For some reason after installing Resharper I couldn't get a global shortcut to work (tried several times!!!), but as long as what you want to do is on the main menu, there is always an Alt + "Letter1", "Letter2" combination to trigger whatever action you'd like :-)

Comment: When resharper is installed it changes some the keyboard shortcuts. You have to disable resharper keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: confirmed, Build Current project works in VS2015 with resharper installed and keyboard scheme set to VS. It also works VS2017 without resharper.

Answer (score 30):

For C# development:

<kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - Builds all the projects in the solution.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> - Builds the selected project and its dependencies.

Comment: Shift-F6 did nothing on VS2013 u5

Comment: Confirmed Shift+F6 works in VS 2015 (I am configured for C# development).

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio 2015/17

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> = Open Build Menu

<kbd>E</kbd> = Rebuild Current Project

Comment: So I tried ALT+B+E, turns out it's rebuild, which means 20 minutes just disappeared into oblivion. Please add comments to what what does? And I actually don't see what rebuild has to do with what Luke was asking.

Answer (score 8):

VS 2012 has <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> already mapped for this. I was surprised to learn this.

Comment: Also available in VS 2017

Answer (score 7):

for C# development. Tools -> Options. Select Keyboard, select additional keyboard mapping scheme to "Visual C# 2005". This mapping has <kbd>F6</kbd> as standard shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2019 this has been set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2017 community, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> then press <kbd>u</kbd> to build your current project.

Details: ALT Switch to the main menu -> choose b for build -> u choose the option of build your_project_name from the drop list.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio **2017** and **2019**, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> works for me.

Answer (score 1):

As Happy Mittal said (Alt + B + J) open a drop window that select the project build, but then i had to press enter instead the last "B" (VS 2017).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> will build your solution and publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have to use Visual Studio in a language different than English and the navigation using <kbd>Alt</kbd> and a combination of keys is different. If there is someone in the same situation, I found out that is more convenient to create a keyboard shortcut to have consistency among languages. I followed the instructions from https://evanjpalmer.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/build-selection-short-cut-for-visual-studio/ to create the keyboard shortcut:

> To set this up:
>
> 1. Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard (Spanish: Herramientas -> Opciones -> Entorno -> Teclado)
> 2. Put the cursor in “Press Keyboard Shortcut Keys” and shift CTRL+SHIFT+B
> 3. In Show Commands Containing, type: Build.BuildSelection (Spanish: Compilar.Compilarselección)
> 4. Select Build.BuildSelection from the drop down list and hit apply
> 5. Put the cursor in “Press Keyboard Shortcut Keys” and shift CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B
> 6. In Show Commands Containing, type: Build.BuildSolution
> 7. Select Build.BuildSolutionfrom the drop down list and hit apply
> 8. ???
> 9. PROFIT!

Answer (score -2):

In the Visual Studio options window, under "Keyboard", look for the "Build.BuildOnlyProject" command and you can set whatever you want.

Comment: Actually this is incorrect, BuildSelection builds the current project.

Comment: -1 This is definitely wrong; though it really should be right.

Comment: BuildSelection builds the project of the currently opened file which may not be the selected (gray background) or startup (listed in bold) project in Solution Explorer.  Executing BuildOnlyProject and RebuildOnlyProject did nothing on my installation (2010).

Comment: Looks like BuildOnlyProject may work in older versions of Visual Studio, or perhaps only with C++. Does not work in VS 2013 with C#, it's not an available command. Unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

press (Alt + B + J + B) these key combinations to build only current selected project of the solution (VS 2010).
It selects "Build" option from toolbar (Alt + B key ) , then goto "project only" (J key ) and then "Build Only XXX" project (B key).